# wordpress get_option('sticky_posts') not returning the whole list of id

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, sticky

I'm using wordpress and [Sticky CPT](https://wordpress.org/plugins/sticky-cpt/) plugin. 
The plugin works fine, i can add sticky option to custom post, and I can see the plugin updating the database list of sticky post.

But I can't filter my query with `'post__not_in' => get_option('sticky_posts')`, because `get_option('sticky_posts')` return only the list of id of 'normal' post, not the whole list of id present in the database. 
It seems to filter the result, and remove all the id of custom post.

Is it the normal get_option('sticky_posts') behavior ?
I would assume it should simply return what's inside the database wp_options/option_name/sticky_posts, am I wrong ?
And if yes, what can I do about it ?

Answer (score 0):

In case it's useful to someone, I ended up:

- dumping the plugin
- and made my own metabox with a simple check box
- then save the post id using the  Options API

and now I can get the id I'm looking for using:

```php
get_option('my_stiky_cpt');
```